# How to Change WooCommerce Product Image Size in WordPress Site?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

[Link to website](http://thehamburgercollection.com/shop/)

I've already followed the instructions here http://www.cbdweb.net/woocommerce-and-image-sizes/
and here https://theme-fusion.com/knowledgebase/how-to-fix-woocommerce-image-size-issues/.

Even though I changed the sizes for Catalogue Image and Product Thumbnails in WooCommerce Settings --> Products --> Display, I still see that the image width and height are set to 300 in the inspector.

When you inspect one of the images, you'll see:

```
<img width="300" height="300"
src="http://thehamburgercollection.com/wp-
content/uploads/2016/10/Screen-Shot-2015-09-19-at-6.00.26-PM-300x300.jpg" 

class="attachment-shop_catalog size-shop_catalog wp-post-image"

alt="Hamburger Collection" title="Hamburger Collection"

srcset="http://thehamburgercollection.com/wp-
content/uploads/2016/10/Screen-Shot-2015-09-19-at-6.00.26-PM-
300x300.jpg 300w, 

http://thehamburgercollection.com/wp-
content/uploads/2016/10/Screen-Shot-2015-09-19-at-6.00.26-PM-
150x150.jpg 150w, 

http://thehamburgercollection.com/wp-
content/uploads/2016/10/Screen-Shot-2015-09-19-at-6.00.26-PM-
180x180.jpg 180w, 

http://thehamburgercollection.com/wp-
content/uploads/2016/10/Screen-Shot-2015-09-19-at-6.00.26-PM-
600x600.jpg 600w" sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px"> == $0
```

With the styles

```
.woocommerce ul.products li.product a img {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
display: block;
margin: 0 0 1em;
box-shadow: none;
}

.woocommerce img, .woocommerce-page img {
height: auto;
max-width: 100%;
}
```

If I try to edit the styles directly in my theme's stylesheet (style.css), I get a pretty bad result:

```
.attachment-shop_catalog .size-shop_catalog .wp-post-image {
width: 400px!important;
height: 400px!important;
}

.woocommerce ul.products li.product a img {
width: 400px!important;
height: 400px!important;
}
```

[image]

If I disable max-width:100% from the style:

```
.woocommerce img, .woocommerce-page img {
height: auto;
max-width: 100%;
}
```

I actually get the correct size, but then the images overlap.
[image]

They also stay at this size when the page responds, which we don't want.

What really doesn't make sense to me, though, is why the img size is still at 300 x 300 when I've already changed the size to 600 x 600 literally everywhere I can think of - in my Stylesheet and for the Catalog Images, Single Product Image, and Product Thumbnails options under WooCommerce Settings --> Products --> Display. I have also regenerated my thumbnails via the Regenerate Thumbnails plugin. Also, the images don't even appear to be 300 x 300 - they actually look like they're 150 x 150 anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The width of your images is currently being dictated by their parent li (list elements).

```
.woocommerce ul.products li.product
```

You have this set to 22.05% of it's parent of 680px. Right now you are forcing your images to be 600px with an !important. You want 2 products per row with a small gap (4%?) between, so this might work better (obviously get rid of the forced 600px width per image):

```
#container .woocommerce ul.products li.product, #container .woocommerce-page ul.products li.product {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 4% 2.992em 0; 
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 46%;
}
```

Did you also check your image sizes in the main Wordpress setup, via Settings -> Media on the admin left-hand menu. If you change these then regenerate your thumbnails again.

Comment: I was just using 600px to get some sort of reaction - what I really want is for both images to take up about half of the "woocommerce" container (each at about 340 px). 

I tried copying and pasting your code into my stylesheet but it brought me back to where I was - small images taking up about 50 % of the width of the woocommerce container.

I did notice that the thumbnail size in Settings --> Media was set to 150 x 150. I thought this might be the problem but I changed it to 300 x 300, saved, and still no result. I already have the regenerate thumbnails plugin installed and activated.

Comment: Settings -> Media probably is the cause. Just to clarify you must re-run the regenerate each time you make a change, it doesn't do it automatically. The code I gave you above would make each product take up 100%. Once you've regenerated your thumbnails again we can take another look.

Comment: Should've mentioned that I did re-run the regenerate thumbnail....the good news is that now the new size (340px) is showing up in the inspector, but it looks like the images are still 150 x 150.....Settings --> Media Thumbnail size is set to 340, and WooCommerce Settings --> Products --> Display Product Thumbnails is set to 340. Changing the size here for Catalog Images (to 340) is what made the size show up differently in the inspector.

Comment: I've edited the answer to better reflect the situation. I tested the answer on Inspect Element in Chrome and it will put your 2 images side by side with a 4% gap. This makes the images 313x313px which is fine as the source image is a little bigger (340px) so you are not losing quality.

Comment: Sorry, still didn't work for me. In the inspector is says that it's pulling the styles from woocommerce.css - in fact, I don't see our style changes anywhere. If you inspect the image, none of our style changes are applied.

Comment: This is because your /wp-content/themes/thehamburgercollection/style.css is being loaded before rather than after the other style sheets. So I can see your code is there, but it's being overwritten due to the cascading nature of the beast. So you need to edit your header.php and bring in your style sheet after the others. In the meantime, you can also use the updated answer (I added #container to make yours more specific and hopefully work even though they come in first, try it).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126278/discussion-between-someguy-and-happyhands31).